# MySQL query where date range is exactly 1 month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to abstract querying a month of data on the MySQL level without having to implement a series of conditions that determine the last day of a given month on a given year. LAST_DAY() seemed to be the answer but it appears to only return the date and not the provided time.

```
SELECT LAST_DAY('2011-02-05 23:59:59');
```

returns

```
2011-02-28
```

When I try to use it in a query, I lose all the entries from the last day of the month because without time the date value is not accepted.

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions
WHERE (`modified_at` BETWEEN '2014-12-01 00:00:01' AND LAST_DAY('2014-12-01 23:59:59'));
```

How can I modify this query so that the LAST_DAY function either generates the last time of the day or preserves the time given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about changing the logic to ignore times?

```
SELECT *
FROM subscriptions
WHERE `modified_at` >= '2014-12-01' AND
      `modified_at` < date_add('2014-12-01', interval 1 month)
```

And this doesn't need `last_day()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ADDTIME(expr1,expr2);
Like this:

```
 ADDTIME(LAST_DAY('2011-02-05 23:59:59'), '23:59:59')
```

Comment: ADDTIME in select statement returns 0000-00-00 00:00:00